# How to replace string with \r\n on node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I want replace string to empty.
What is wrong this code?

```
var fs = require('fs')
fs.readFile('requestSongs.txt', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }
  var result = data.replace(new RegExp('\\r\\n' + songCurrent[1],'g'),"");    
  fs.writeFile('requestSongs.txt', result, 'utf8', function (err) {
     if (err) return console.log(err);
  });
});
```

Comment: can you give a example of the string , in which you want to replace? and also what is the disired output?

Comment: Are you sure you have `songCurrent[1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You should sure you use windows line break `CRLF` (`\r\n`)
- Test `songCurrent[1]` with `console.log(songCurrent[1])` to know you file match `songCurrent[1]`

I have `requestSongs.txt` (`CRLF`)

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
line6
line7
```

`index.js`:

```
var fs = require('fs')

songCurrent = [0, 'line3']

fs.readFile('requestSongs.txt', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }
  var result = data.replace(new RegExp('\\r\\n' + songCurrent[1],'g'),"");    
  fs.writeFile('requestSongs.txt', result, 'utf8', function (err) {
     if (err) return console.log(err);
  });
})
```

I run `node index.js`, this is `requestSongs.txt`, don't have any problem:

```
line1
line2
line4
line5
line6
line7
```